# 腰が逃げそうになる >> What does this mean about a person's hip? Does it mean that it became disjointed/tired?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

**腰が逃げそうになる**

When I searched this phrase on Google, it showed me some images about golf, so my guess is that it means a person's hip became dislocated and/or tired due to excessive exercising.

Can someone tell me the correct meaning? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the term is used in a hitting using a bat or golf club or etc.
According to [this site related to baseball technique](https://batting-koshien.net/entry19.html),

> 腰が引けるとも言いますが体の重心が外側にかかってしまい当てるだけのバッティングになってしまいます。

*“It is also called 腰が引ける. The center of the gravity of the body is inclined to outside the body, so his/her batting gets just touching to the ball.”*

The gif image shows Fujinami, a hanshin tigers pitcher, is widely known for often losing control of his pitching due to yips and a hitter is afraid of his ball which might strike batter’s head or arm.

[image]